# how variable scope works in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

```
var change = 1;

$("#game").click(function (e) {
    if (change == 1) {
        var data = $(e.target).closest("td").text();
        var p1 = $("#player1").val();
        var p1_value = p1 + data;
        $("#player1").val(p1_value);
        change = 2;
    } else(change == 2) {
        var data = $(e.target).closest("td").text();
        var p2 = $("#player2").val();
        var p2_value = p2 + data;
        $("#player2").val(p1_value);
        change = 1;
    }

});
```

Is it the write way to write? BTW here it is not going to the else loop.

Comment: @jijq what is the problem in above code??

Comment: jQuery isn't a language you know. JavaScript is a language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has only [function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope), not "curly bracket scope". If you want to be very correct, you would put all the declarations at the top of the function:

```
$("#game").click(function(e) {
    var data = '',
        p1 = '',
        p1_value = '',
        p2 = '',
        p2_value = '';

        if (change == 1) {
            data = $(e.target).closest("td").text();
            p1 = $("#player1").val();
            p1_value = p1 + data;
            $("#player1").val(p1_value);
            change = 2;
        }
        else if (change == 2) { // you forgot `if`
            data = $(e.target).closest("td").text();
            p2 = $("#player2").val();
            p2_value = p2 + data;
            $("#player2").val(p1_value);
            change = 1;
        }
});
```

At least [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) complains about `data` being already defined.

But you can optimize (and shorten!) your function in another way:

```
$("#game").click(function(e) {
    var $player = $('#player' + change);
    $player.val($player.val() + $(e.target).closest("td").text());
    change = (change === 1) ? 2 : 1;
}
```

Comment: +1 I was trying to leave an example like your last one, but did two really stupid things. Stupid 1: Accidentally created infinite loop. Stupid 2: Used `alert()`. You'd think I'd learn by now!

Comment: @patrick dw: Poor you... I know how annoying *that* can be ;)

Comment: Thank you. Your pity is wholly accepted. ;o) Funny thing is that I can't see the loop. I did effectively your solution, but forgot to change `toggle` to `click` from my example (and, of course, added the alert). There aren't any `for` type loops, so somehow the click is being continuously triggered.

Comment: Also: `$player.val(function(i,v) { return v + $(e.target).closest("td").text(); });`

Comment: Also, caching the jQuery objects would be reasonable: `var players = [$("#player1"), $("#player2")];` (outside of the click hadler). And then just: `players[change-1].val(...`

Comment: @Felix: In case you're interested, looks like when setting up the toggle event, jQuery *triggers* the handler, and if your javascript throws *any* kind of error, the handler continuously fires (in Safari/Chrome anyway). `$("div").toggle(function(e){throw('something');});` If there's a `<div>` on the page, there's an automatic infinite loop. Off to the bug tracker...

Comment: @patrick dw: Interesting. *And now you shall go to the bug tracker.*

Comment: I'm going to file it, but I'm really not certain that it could be considered a bug, since passing 1 function is not proper usage of the method.

Comment: @patrick dw: Actually it is, there are two versions of this method: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ and http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/. The first one only accepts one callback. And now that I see it, if you use only one function, you are *not* binding the function as `click` event handler... it is just the callback that is called after the element is hidden (or shown) (this "method overloading" can be really confusing in jQuery). It is still a bug imo.

Comment: @Felix: Yep, I just realized that about a minute after filing. I should have checked back here first. I had actually filed it [as an enhancement](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7752) to give consideration to a single function passed as a typical `click()`. Then it hit me, so I updated it with a comment. In my opinion, it is a very unfortunate decision to have the same method perform entirely different tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` should be an `else if` if you intend to use the condition:

```
if (change == 1) {
    // ...
} else if(change == 2) {
    // ...
}
```

As perhaps a better alternative, you can use jQuery's `.toggle()`, and pass it two functions which alternate on clicks.

```
$("#game").toggle(function(e) {
            var data = $(e.target).closest("td").text();
            var p1 = $("#player1").val();
            var p1_value = p1 + data;
            $("#player1").val(p1_value);
 }, function(e) {
            var data = $(e.target).closest("td").text();
            var p2 = $("#player2").val();
            var p2_value = p2 + data;
            $("#player2").val(p1_value);
 });
```